# What is an example of a URL that is not a URI?

Tags: java, url, uri

In `java.net`, we have the two classes `URI` and `URL`.

I get why some `URI`s cannot be converted to a `URL`, but I cannot find an example of a `URL` that cannot be converted to a `URI`.
Yet, the `toURI()` method of `URL` can throw a `URISyntaxException`.

This makes sense when you look at the code, since `toURI()` utilizes the constructor of `URI`, but am I the only one thinking that they could rightfully choke the exception in `toURI()`?
Am I missing a point?